# How to localize html strings in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I want to write html code locally and show it in UIWebview ,so for this ,I have taken a simple html code ,as below and created a .html extension file..

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I added this file into my xcode project ,now I want to load this file inside webview ,so I have written this code

```
[m_websiteView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

but the output I get when I run this code in UIWebView is same htmlcode, I cant figure out what the problem is..but when I tried using this code

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString *testString = @"<h1><i>This is an image using reference in HTML</i></h1>"
    "<img src='active.png'></img>";
    [m_websiteView loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:baseURL];
```

this works perfect.also I want to localize the strings in this html code,so in the above code,how can I localize this string "This is an image using reference in HTML"..

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add localization, use this

```
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"<h1><i>%@</i></h1><img src='active.png'></img>",
   NSLocalizedString(@"This is an image using reference in HTML", @"htmlText")];
```

and specify the localize strings in the file `Localizable.strings` in the correct language directory.

You can also localized entire (HTML) files with the locale directory scheme.

Comment: hey mundi,thanks for your reply,its working fine..as you said ,entire html file can be localized with locale directory scheme,I didnt understand this, will you please explain this..

Comment: In Xcode select the HTML file, in the right panel go to the file inspector and you will find a section "Localization". Press the "+" button and add the language you want. Now in the project navigator, the file has become like a folder with the editable language versions underneath. You can do this with any file, images, nibs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

HTML syntax is

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

after that you can preview your html file using something like that in your view controller

```
CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.istoselidas.gr";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self addSubview:webView]; 
[webView release];
```

just replace url with your html file